# not able to open files in windows partition from linux on a dual boot system

Tags: linux, fedora

I have installed dual boot on my laptop, windows XP && Fedora linux. For some unknown reason windows XP is not booting up. Through fedora I'm able to see the windows XP partition and files in it. But the problem here is, I'm not able to open those files from linux. Does anybody hit this kind of issue, if so and incase you figured out the soluton, can you please share the solution?

Thanks in advance.

```
~ $ cat /etc/fstab
tmpfs     /dev/shm   tmpfs   defaults       0 0
devpts    /dev/pts   devpts  gid=5,mode=620 0 0
sysfs     /sys       sysfs   defaults       0 0
proc      /proc      proc    defaults       0 0
/dev/sda1 /windows   ntfs    defaults       0 0
```

Comment: What is configuration are you using? Can you past the output of `mount` or `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: Here is the following output:tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda1               /windows                ntfs    defaults        0 0